# HTML5 onclick button does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html file which must to call one function under onclick, however does not execute anything, neither alerts. I dont know what happend with this button.The button does not works is "id=botonRegistro" (any button works really).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script> -->
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions_v1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/objects_v1.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>KirolAPP</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="registerPage">
        <div data-role="header" align="center">
            <img src="img/kirolLogo.png"> <br>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" align="center" id="registerContent">
            <form id="formRegistro">
                <br> <input type="text" id="idNombreReg" style="border: 1;" placeholder="Nombre"><br>
                <input type="text" id="idSec" style="border: 1;" placeholder="1ºApellido"><br>
                <input type="text" id="idLast" style="border: 1;" placeholder="2ºApellido"><br>
                <input type="password" id="idClaveReg" style="border: 1; color: orange;" placeholder="Clave"><br>
                <input type="password" id="idClaveRegRep" style="border: 1; color: orange;" placeholder="Confirmar clave"><br>
                <input type="email" id="idEmail" style="border: 1;" placeholder="Email"><br>
                <button type="button" id="botonRegistro" onclick="alert('Registrado!')">Registrarse</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div  data-role="content" id="back" style="text-align: center; display: none" >
            <a href="index.html" id="botonBack">Volver</a>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried with

```
onclick="alert('hello');"
```

and I think that onclick does not need a prefix, so... I don't know what happened with this code, because does not calls javascript functions.

Edit: This is my css

```
body{
    background-image: url("../img/fondoIndex.png");
    background-size: inherit                       
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Edit with solution:

I had not added "inline-unsafe" to default-src, like this:

> https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'
>   'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors ?

Comment: The alert works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/56uje6bu/  Maybe all of that JavaScript you're loading in the header is throwing errors?

Comment: Your onclick is working fine. Do you have any events binded to this button already? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Can we see your css? It may be that the button is not actually being clicked due to an overlapping element.

Comment: My console does not shows anything. Im on Eclipse ADT.

Comment: I removed the line <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> and it worked, but i cant understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why but the content security policy block it.
When i delete this meta all works:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: This worked, but i dont know why. It must works with it added.

Comment: The error I get in Chrome is `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Answer (score 1):

Update the meta tag to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I added `'unsafe-inline'` to the `default-src` directive to allow the `onClick()` to execute.