# switch background images MVC

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the following css definition to load a background image.

```
body, html {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("../images/image1.png");
background-size: 100%;
}
```

The background image is now displayed on every page. However, we want to switch between "image1.png" and "image2.png" for different applications. Is there a simple way to switch the images by adding some JavaScript code and a button in `_layout.cshtml` file?

Comment: What do you mean by switch between image1 and image 2 for different applications? If app1 display image1? if app2, display image2? Or do you really want a button to click by the user to swtich the images?

Comment: We try to give a demo to different customers. Before the customer comes, we want to display a specific image to the specific customer. It can a button or some other mechanism.

Comment: Add a class with CSS for each option and change the class on those elements perhaps?

Comment: You could create two seperate pages with the image you want in each page, then just navigate to the url with the image you want to show, or you could create two classes one for each image, then switch your class in your html before running it...etc.

Comment: I cannot use two pages because the page is my IdentityServer4 login page. I am thinking to put the image url in java script code with logical switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use jQuery to switch the background-image.  I just wired this up to an HTML anchor tag and set its onclick handler to this function.  "imageId" is the id of the img element on my page.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function switchImage() {
   $('#imageId').css('background-image', "url('imageToReplace.png')");
}
```

or by customer (psuedo)

```
function switchImage(customerImageUrl) {
    $('#imageId').css('background-image', "url('+ customerImageUrl +')");
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" onclick="switchImage()">Switch</a>
```

or by customer

```
 <a href="#" onclick="switchImage('customer1.png')">Switch to Customer 1</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="switchImage('customer2.png')">Switch to Customer 2</a>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {   
 var el = document.getElementById("button1");  
 if (el) {  
  addEventListener("click", switchImage1());  
 }  
 var el2 = document.getElementById("button2");  
 if (el2) {  
  addEventListener("click", switchImage2());  
 }  
});  
function switchImage1() {  
 $('body, html').css('background-image', "url  ('../images/image1.png')");  
}
function switchImage2() {  
 $('body, html').css('background-image', "url  ('../images/image2.png')");  
}`

Comment: I am trying to format above code and timed out. I added two buttons: "button1" and "button2". It seems they are not working when I clicked. It only works when addEventListerner runs. It ends up "image2" as the background image.

Comment: Looks like you are planning for a button for each customer, correct?   If so, I would recommend just having what I described in the answer and have the function take the customer info (id and image url).  By using $(document).ready you are already using jQuery anyway...no harm in my mind just sending in your params from the button and keeping the function small and concise considering your proof of concept use case.   I will update answer to show what I mean.

Comment: chrome doesn't allow direct "onClick" in the element. That is why I used "addEventListener". However, I cannot make it working.

Comment: What type of element is it?   Chrome allows onclick events on anchor tags.   Just tested it on button element also....this also works in chrome.

Comment: It is C# cshtml file. I used to two buttons and it gave me errors if I used "onClick" directly.

Comment: what errors are you getting?  cshtml file type shouldn't have any bearing on whether onclick is handled by the browser

Comment: Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Not sure if you can change this meta tag or not but refer to this other SO question for that error.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513009/html5-onclick-button-does-not-works

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, have two classes for body in css, and place the different image path there.

```
body.background1 {
  background-image: url("../images/image1.png");
}
body.background2 {
  background-image: url("../images/image2.png");
}
```

and then, you can change the background image by just replacing the class in body element in javascript.